# Duplicated site isn't recognized as a site

Tags: database, mysql, wp-cli, testing

I've duplicated a site using the following code. All code worked fine until the last row (the site itself goes up on the web but the last row of code fails and I get an error):

```
echo "Please enter the domain of the site for duplication"
read domain
echo "Please enter the password of the site's DB user"
read -s psw

cp -r /var/www/html/${domain} /var/www/html/test
sed -i "s/${domain}/test"/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
    DROP user IF EXISTS 'test'@'localhost'; SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
    DROP database IF EXISTS test; show databases;

    CREATE user 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${psw}';
    CREATE database test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;
MYSQL

cd /var/www/html/test
wp search-replace "${domain}" "test" --allow-root
```

The last WPCLI command outputs:

> Error: The site you have requested is not installed.

The same goes for other WPCLI commands. For some reason, WPCLI doesn't recognize my `test` site.

Any idea why WPCLI doesn't recognize my site when I'm clearly inside its directory?

### Update for motivast:

```
mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
    DROP user IF EXISTS 'test'@'localhost'; SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
    DROP database IF EXISTS test; show databases;

    CREATE user 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${psw}';
    CREATE database test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;
MYSQL

mysqldump -u root -p ${domain} > test.sql
mysql -u root -p test < test.sql
```

Did I have the logic right? Did I passed the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is from the last command `wp search-replace "${domain}" "test" --allow-root`. Your WordPress site is not yet installed and you want to execute command which require WordPress to be installed.

Earlier in script you are dropping `test` database and creating new one, but you have to fill it with WordPress tables. Without this tables WordPress is not installed as the error says. You have to install WordPress by visiting your test page in the browser or execute `wp core install` with arguments in the command line.

You can also duplicate your database using `mysqldump` and `mysql` commands:

Dump: `mysqldump -u root -p [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`

Import: `mysql -u root -p [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql`

Following script will make this for your:

```
#!/bin/bash
#===================================================================================
#
# FILE: wpdup.sh
#
# USAGE: wpdup.sh <dir_old> <dir_new> <dbname_old> <dbname_new> <dbuser_new> <dbpass_new> <domain_old> <domain_new>
#
# DESCRIPTION: Duplicate WP installation with database and replace domain.
#
# OPTIONS: see function ’usage’ below
#===================================================================================

EXPECTED_ARGS=8
E_BADARGS=65

if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <dir_old> <dir_new> <dbname_old> <dbname_new> <dbuser_new> <dbpass_new> <domain_old> <domain_new>"
  exit $E_BADARGS 
fi

MYSQL=`which mysql`
MYSQLDUMP=`which mysqldump`
WP=`which wp`
CP=`which cp`

TMPDIR='/tmp'

DIR_OLD=$1
DIR_NEW=$2

DBNAME_OLD=$3
DBNAME_NEW=$4

DBUSER_NEW=$5
DBPASS_NEW=$6

DOMAIN_OLD=$7
DOMAIN_NEW=$8

echo -n "Enter root mysql password:"
read -s DBROOT_PASS

echo "Copy directory"
# Copy WP site  
$CP -r $DIR_OLD $DIR_NEW

echo "Dump database"
# Dump database
$MYSQLDUMP -u root -p$DBROOT_PASS $DBNAME_OLD > "${TMPDIR}/dbdump.sql"

# Create new database if not exists and add privileges.
Q1="DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $DBNAME_NEW;"
Q2="DROP USER '$DBUSER_NEW'@'localhost';"
Q3="CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME_NEW COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
Q4="CREATE USER '$DBUSER_NEW'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$DBPASS_NEW';"
Q5="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $DBNAME_NEW.* TO '$DBUSER_NEW'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$DBPASS_NEW';"
Q6="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}${Q4}${Q5}${Q6}"

echo "Create database"
$MYSQL -e "${SQL}" -u root -p$DBROOT_PASS

echo "Import database"
# Import dumped database
$MYSQL -u root -p$DBROOT_PASS $DBNAME_NEW < "${TMPDIR}/dbdump.sql"

echo "Create wp config"
# Create new wordpress config
cd $DIR_NEW && $WP core config --dbname=${DBNAME_NEW} --dbuser=${DBUSER_NEW} --dbpass=${DBPASS_NEW} --dbhost="localhost" --allow-root --skip-check --force

echo "Replace domain"
# Replace domain in new wp site
cd $DIR_NEW && $WP search-replace "${DOMAIN_OLD}" "${DOMAIN_NEW}" --allow-root
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
sudo ./wpdup.sh /var/www/test /var/www/testnew wp_test wp_testnew wp_testnew xxxxxx test.dev testnew.dev
```

Comment: I need to duplicate all DB data from the original site to `test`. Do you know a way to do that? If I'll install the core from scratch I won't have that data so I need to somehow complete the script to have that data.

Comment: You can use `mysqldump` command to dump database and `mysql` to import it. Dump `mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql` import `mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql`

Comment: I should put that inside the `MYSQL` heredocument I guess? In this case, a password is really needed? I mean, I already logged in to `mysql` CLI as root. Please show this in an answer, I will gladly give you a 100 points bounty the moment I could.

Comment: There is not mysqldump equivalent in SQL language you have to execute this statements as separate commands. If you omit password you would be simply asked for it.

Comment: I swear I will give you 100 bounty for this help the moment I can (StackExchange let me give in about 43 hours from now) but I have putted this session in my browser's favorite's bar and I will give you a bounty. Please just one last thing, dear @mottivast. Please see my update in the question, I think I got this logically and right, one after the other, and the script is completed now.

Comment: Your edit seems to be ok. If you want I try can provide you ready script but I can't do it now but for about 10h.

Comment: Sure, no problem, I would be glad to read the full script, than read my code again, and make sure I learn this the best way possible. I am going to sleep soon and will gladly read it by then.

Comment: I would be most honored, dear @motivast.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I now offer bounty and the system allowed me to award it in 24 hours from now. Small note, I think the comment header in the script and the answer can go down (I think these details better be outside the script, here in the answer).

Comment: Dear @motivast you are more than welcome to answer on a question of mine here as well, and I offer bounty there as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409124/exporting-and-importing-a-mysqldump-from-within-a-mysql-cli-heredocument